# UIWebView not loading the XHTML file properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a sample.xhtml file which has few lines of javascript. This javascript will load a pdf file from the net.

If I use simple .xhtml file, it is loading properly. If I use Javascript, the webView is not displaying the .xhtml file properly

```
[_webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"application/xhtml+xml" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   

 //NSString *strHTML;  (.h)
 [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:strHTML baseURL:nil];
 }

//delegate

 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strHTML];
}
```

Comment: Ya. NSString type. I am using the following code . 
filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"xhtml"];

NSURL*  url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
[_webView loadHTMLString:filePath baseURL:nil];           Is this Right ?

Answer (score 0):

try this. to load your file path

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
  filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"xhtml"]; 
  NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; 
  [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: If you want to changes in your answer then dont update it in new answer ....just edit in your previous answer....: